# сборка образа Docker если аргумент не передан

Tags: docker

Есть Dockerfile

`FROM ubuntu:14.04
LABEL maintainer="Vasya"
...
ARG UID
RUN mkdir /home/vasya && useradd -r -u $UID vasya && chown vasya /home/vasya
....`

Когда делаю сборку с аргументом, все нормально

`docker bulld -t myimage --build-arg UID=2222 .`

А как сделать так, если аргумент UID не передан и аргументом по умолчанию будет id хоста, т.е. должна быть выполнен вот такая команда

`docker build -t myimage .`

Answer (score 0):

UID пользователя на хостовой машине можно прокинуть только через **ARG**.

```
docker bulld -t myimage --build-arg UID=$( id -u ) .
```

Чтобы сборка не ломалась без указания аргумента, можно указать значение по-умолчанию https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#default-values

```
ARG UID=2222
```